# How to open a pdf within Python Kivy app?

Tags: python, pdf, kivy, kivy-language

I've searched about this but found nothing. Only opening images has documented. Maybe I can open a page as an image but I want full access on text like copy/paste and highlighting.

Is there any way to open a pdf within a kivy app?

Comment: You can have python open the document using a pdf reader on your computer.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes I can do it like that but pdf reader opens up in different window. I want to implement it to kivy gui window not open it in a separate window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by Kivy. PDF rendering and interaction is quite complicated, I don't know how difficult it would be to implement.

Comment: Yes, I need to figure out in a different way. Thanks for answer and stay safe...